# How do I overcome this issue : ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION in phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I had developed an application using phonegap.And I tried to generate apk for my application using phonegap build but I get this issue while generating apk (Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference: ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION) .

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screensize" source="npm" />
```

I used these three plugins in my phonegap application.Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3):

@ Javith J
i get it: its the social sharing plugin - so basically we have to configure the plugin itself. I had the same issue.

Solution:

in your config.xml file change the version number of the social-sharing-x plugin to 5.4.0

see:

```
<plugin name = "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" version="5.4.0" />
```

After that i can build it and everything works fine.

Best,

Thomas

Comment: Is this still up-to-date? I can see that the latest release of the plugin is 5.6.3 (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe PhoneGap recommends specifying the plugin version. 
In your config.xml file, specifying the spec version of the plugins used.
Below are the sample plugins and their specified versions.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" spec="1.2.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="1.0.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="1.0.9" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.4.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

has an issue and fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/mj/projects/benara-sales-client/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 266

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

To fix, you may install v5.4.0

so remove the plugin and the correct version

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing@5.4.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a quick fix: it is cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing. Not social-sharing.